# VueJS: Changing SCSS variable Colors dynamically or import scss files dynamically

Tags: vue.js, sass, scss-mixins

I'm having sub-Domains like xyz.in/ab, xyz.in/bc , etc.. which runs in a single server. I need to config different styles for different domain. So I need to change the primary, secondary, ..etc colors dynamically.

ab.scss

```
$primary: white, 
$secondary: grey
```

bc.scss

```
$primary: red, 
$secondary: light-grey
```

I need to config different files dynamically based on URL (note: I need change the files dynamically on run time). How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can not edit Sass variables at run time. It's a CSS preprocessor and needs to be compiled. Maybe custom properties is the way to go, you can easily edit them with Js.

Answer (score 1):

If the url is `xyz.in/ab`, then `this.$route.path` should give you `/ab`.
Then you can try ES6 dynamic import to solve your problem like this:

```
mounted() {
    /* figure out the scss file name according to url */
    const fileName = this.$route.path === '/ab' ? 'one.scss' : 'two.scss';

    /* import file dynamically (assuming scss files are in assets/scss folder) */
    import("@/assets/scss/" + fileName);
}
```

Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: I have tried as you mentioned above. It doesn't works. Thanks @saibbyweb

Comment: I updated the code with a tried and tested example. You can do the comparison in the mounted hook of the component using `this.route.path` instead of 'window.location.path'

Comment: I have already tried this. Not working for me.

Comment: It may be work for you , In my case we are setting theme variable in scss file. Once it loaded we couldn't overwrite the theme variables.